# How to share only realtime data with users?

Tags: google-analytics, real-time

I want to share the real time overview in Google Analytics with my editors. But I don't want to share the full view data. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

- Create new view, which contains all site data
- Read [this article](https://danielmiessler.com/blog/creating-a-realtime-traffic-dashboard-with-google-analytics/),
- import [this dashboard](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=duiZ5K49S3-mG_x7lWIvkA)
- add the imported dashboard to the newly created view

...

Then you get the live dashboard, which contains your real time data and the sharing option (highlighted on screenshot)
[image]

...

- Profit!

Comment: Hey @Evgeniy, thanks for the reply. But is there  a way of sharing a custom dashboard only? I mean, the users will also have access to Real-Time, Audience..and other links to the left? Won't they? Or am I missing something?

Comment: as i understand (haven't test it by my own), if you share the dashboard, users will haven't access to nothing more - only to the dashboard and what is displayed on it. no other data, no other links.

Comment: I tested it on my own alternative email id. I can access everything else, which defeats the whole purpose of creating the dashboard. The shared dashboard appears under "Shared" in Dashboards.